# how to reference a control in a subform in tab control

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I have two combo boxes in the form "FindCost" named
cboProject , and cboDate. The cboDate values are filtered from cboProject using the below SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.[period end date], F.Project 
FROM FindHr AS F 
WHERE F.Project=[Forms]![FindCost]![cboProjects];
```

The above worked when "FindCost" was an independent form. But since I moved it into the main form "Panel" , I am having trouble referencing cboProject again.

"FindCost" becomes "SubFormFind", which is a page on tab control "tabActuals", which is part of the main form "Panel".

I have tried

```
WHERE F.Project = Forms![Panel]![subFormFind]![FindCost]![cboProject]
```

and also use the "build expressions" in the SQL design. but both prove to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The tab control is irrelevant, ensure you use the name of the subform control, not the form contained http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa! Too many objects referenced -- incorrectly.  I believe you should have

```
WHERE F.Project = Forms![Panel]![subFormFind]![cboProject] 
                       ^^FORM     ^^Subform    ^^Control
```

Comment: Subform control, not the name of the form contained, they can be different.